# python script for removing duplicates taking 24 hrs+ to loop through 10^7 records

Tags: python, optimization

**input t1**
P95P,71655,LINC-JP,pathogenic
P95P,71655,LINC-JP,pathogenic
P71P,71655,LINC-JP,pathogenic
P71P,71655,LINC-JP,pathogenic

**output *op***
P95P,71655,LINC-JP,pathogenic
P71P,71655,LINC-JP,pathogenic

**myCode**

```
def dup():
    fi=open("op","a")
    l=[];final="";
    q=[];dic={};
    for i in open("t1"):
        k=i.split(",")
        q.append(k[1])
        q.append(k[0])
        if q in l:
            pass
        else:
            final= final + i.strip() + "\n"
            fi.write(str(i.strip()))
            fi.write("\n")
        l.append(q)
        q=[]
        #print i.strip()
    fi.close()
    return final.strip()    
d=dup()
```

In the above input line1,2 and line 3,4 are duplicates. Hence in output these duplicates are removed  the entries in my input files are around 10^7.

**Why is my code running since past 24 hrs for an input of 76Mb file.** Also it has yet to complete one iteration of entire input file.It works fine for small files.
Can anyone please point out the reason for this long time.How can I optimize my program ? 
thnx

Comment: Have you considered making `l` a `set` instead of a `list`? Membership checking would be `O(1)` instead of `O(len(l))`. Also, don't `append` (or `add` if you use a `set`) to `l` in the `if q in l:` case.

Comment: @jonrsharpe what if file is bigger say 1 gb. does set works?

Comment: Will duplicates always be next to each other?

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар what do you mean *"does set works"*? If you have enough system memory, it shouldn't be a problem. The lookup performance is based on hashing, so would remain at `O(1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear why you're building a huge string (`final`) that holds the same thing the file does, or what `dic` is for. In terms of performance, you can look up `x in y` much faster if `y` is a `set` than if `y` is a `list`. Also, a minor point; shorter variable names don't improve performance, so use good ones instead. I would suggest:

```
def deduplicate(infile, outfile):
    seen = set()
    #final = []
    with open(outfile, "a") as out, open(infile) as in_:
        for line in in_:
            check = tuple(line.split(",")[:2])
            if check not in seen:
                #final.append(line.strip())
                out.write(line) # why 'strip' the '\n' then 'write' a new one?
                seen.add(check)
    #return "\n".join(final)
```

If you do really need final, make it a list until the last moment (see commented-out lines) - gradual string concatenation means the creation of lots of unnecessary objects.

Comment: final is used for returning the non-duplicates to another file for analysis

Comment: @diablo8226 why not do that file writing in this function too?

Comment: yea i wish i had done that but i cant kill the execution now.But i will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 6):

You're using an O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm, which scales poorly for larger files:

```
for i in open("t1"):  # linear pass of file takes O(n) time
    ...
    if q in l:  # linear pass of list l takes O(n) time
        ...
    ...
```

You should consider using a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) (i.e. make `l` a `set`) or [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) if duplicates will always be next to each other. These approaches will be O(n).

Comment: how to correctly determine the complexity of any code ? I estimated my code to be of O(N) complexity since it has one iteration. Are there any tutorials for specifically determining the algo complexity ? thnx

Comment: @diablo8226 It's not necessarily a trivial task. In your specific case, it's O(n^2) because on each iteration of the outer loop, you have to perform another O(n) operation by looping over `l` (this is O(n) because `l` will presumably grow to be proportional to n in size). Note that n here is the length of your file in lines.

Answer (score 5):

if you have access to a Unix system, `uniq` is a nice utility that is made for your problem.

```
uniq input.txt output.txt
```

see https://www.cs.duke.edu/csl/docs/unix_course/intro-89.html

I know this is a `Python` question, but sometimes `Python` is not the tool for the task.
And you can always embed a system call in your python script.

Comment: what system are you using ?

Comment: uea i have but uniq didnt work on the data..i mean it didnt weed out the duplicates.
i used `uniq -u "file_name"`

Comment: what about `uniq file_name` where filename is the path to the file containing the data?

Comment: the cmd is working but the o/p is the same as original

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things that you are doing very inefficiently. The largest is that you made `l` a list, so the line `if q in l` has to search through everything in the list already in order to check if q matches it. If you make l a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set), the membership check can be done using a hash calculation and array lookup, which take the same (small) amount of time no matter how much you add to the set (though it will cause `l` not to be read in the order that it was written).

Other little speedups that you can do include:

- Using a tupple `(k[1], k[0])` instead of a list for `q`.
- You are writing your output file `fi` every loop. Your OS will try to batch and background the writes, but it may be faster to just do one big write at the end. I am not sure on this point but try it.

Comment: writing to "fi" is to play safe.Suppose, my system gets accidentally shut-down or if i have to restart it.If i write the non-duplicates in  "fi" then next time while running the program i don't have to give the entire input again.